# Unexpected answer on multiplying vector.size() with string.length() in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, casting

Consider this code

```
string A("a");
vector<string>B={"a","a"};
cout<<A.length()<<endl;;
cout<<B[0].length()<<endl;;
cout<<B.size()<<endl;
cout<<(A.length()-(B[0].length()*B.size()))<<endl;
cout<<(int)(A.length()-(B[0].length()*B.size()))<<endl;
```

The output of above code is

```
1
1
2
18446744073709551615
-1
```

string::length and string::size is in bytes and vector::size is unsigned integer. Why is the output like that, what is the meaning of `18446744073709551615`, what is the datatype of `(A.length()-(B[0].length()*B.size()))` and why did integer casting give correct answer?

Comment: I am sure there are more than one duplicates of this question at SO. A negative number -> an unsigned type results in a large number. Be careful with your math. Don't do it. If possible, used signed types when you are in need of subtracting the numbers.

Comment: The result of the cast is implementation-defined behaviour. To be well-defined you could cast each operand to `int` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

size_t are strictly made for storing the sizes and lengths that obviously cannot be negative. It is unsigned in nature and implementation dependent.
your code is forcing a negative value to a size_t type and hence you see this strange number.

As done correctly by you, the result must be cast to a data type which can accept a negative value.

Run the following self explanatory code:
(This should give you same result)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::size_t size = -1;
    std::cout << size; 
}
```

Comment: Also, when `int p=1` and `unsigned q=-1` Why is `p<q` true? What happens when `relational operation` is done on `different data types`?